# Coredump when parsing chapters

Tags: c, pointers

I am doing a homework assignment that reads in a book.  First, a line is read in and a pointer made to point at that line. Then a paragraph function reads in lines and stores their address into a array of pointers.  Now, I am on reading a chapter (a paragraph recognized by the next line being broke). It should call `get_paragraph()` and store the address of paragraphs until it comes to a new chapter.

A new chapter is the only time in the book where the first character in the line is not a space. I think this is were I am having problems in my code. All functions up to this point work. I hope I have provided enough information. The code compiles but core dumps when started.

I am a student and learning so please be kind. Thanks.

```
char*** get_chapter(FILE * infile){

    int i=0;

    char **chapter[10000];//an array of pointers 
    // Populate the array
    while(chapter[i]=get_paragraph(infile)) { //get address store into array
      if(!isspace(**chapter[0])){    //check to see if it is a new chapter<---problem line?
        // save paragraph not used in chapter using static to put into next chapter
        break;
      }
      i++;//increment array
    }
    //add the null
    chapter[++i]='\0';//put a null at the end to signify end of array
    //Malloc the pointer
    char**(*chap) = malloc(i * sizeof(*chap));//malloc space
    //Copy the array to the pointer
    i=0;//reset address
    while(chapter[i]){//while there are addresses in chapter
      chap[i] = chapter[i++];//change addresses into chap
    }
    chap[i]='\0';//null to signify end of chapter
    //Return the pointer
    return(chap);//return pointer to array
  }
```

For those who would rather see without comments:

```
 char*** get_chapter(FILE * infile){

    int i=0;

    char **chapter[10000];
    while(chapter[i]=get_paragraph(infile)) { 
      if(!isspace(**chapter[0])){   
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    chapter[++i]='\0';
    char**(*chap) = malloc(i * sizeof(*chap));//malloc space
    i=0;
    while(chapter[i]){
      chap[i] = chapter[i++];
    }
    chap[i]='\0';
    return(chap);
  }
```

Comment: I don't know why anyone would need to see your code *without* comments. What we need to see is properly formatted code. Use the 1010 button to indent the whole code block by four spaces after you paste it. Then fix up the rest of the indentation so it makes sense. This will be easier if you indent it right in an editor that only uses space characters **before** you paste it into SO, then use the 1010 button to make it format as code.

Comment: Thanks, in my code I actually have a #define CHAPTERLIM in my code, but through in that number so did not have to explain it, but I edited the post now.  So it looked like char ** chapter[CHAPTERLIM];

Comment: This is one of the better homework questions that I've seen in a while. I'm making your first paragraph a bit easier to read.

Comment: Well explained, but I've edited the title to be less generic and more about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest that you use `for` loops instead of `while`s? You need to stop if you run out of space, so you might as well use the appropriate construct.

I suspect you have a bug in this code:

```
while(chapter[i]=get_paragraph(infile)) { 
  if(!isspace(**chapter[0])){   
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
chapter[++i]='\0';
```

Firstly, shouldn't it be `chapter[i]` instead of `chapter[0]`? You want to know if the pointer at `chapter[i]` points to a space, not the first pointer in `chapter`. So this will probably loop indefinitely - hence the need for a `for` loop, so you don't just loop forever accidentally.

Secondly, you increment `i` at the end of the while block, and then again in the `chapter[++i]` assignment. `i` has already been incremented by the final loop execution before the while condition breaks, so it is already the correct position to use. `++i` increments *before* yielding the value, so presumably you meant to have `i++` here, so that it would increment *after* yielding the current value of `i`. Either way, it's confusing one of us as to what you mean, so maybe just put the increment on a separate line for clarity. The compiler will sort out any available optimisation.

Finally (and I might well be wrong here) why are you setting the value to `'\0'`? That's a null character, isn't it? But your array is of pointers. The null pointer would be `0`, rather than `'\0'`, I think. If I'm right, you might have still got away with it if `'\0'` yields the same set of zeroes as the null pointer.

Comment: `'\0'` is an integer constant with value zero, just like 0 and 0LL are.  I can't recall the finer points of C's conversions for zero integer constants to pointer types, nor how char literals having type int may affect this, but I strongly suspect it's treated identically to how 0, 0L, or 0LL would be, rather than it merely happens to yield the same set of zeros.  That said, you covered everything I noticed and was going to answer with. :)

Comment: @Roger Pate: That's correct, in C `'\0'` behaves exactly like `0`, including the ability to use either as a null pointer constant.  The only difference is in the meaning it conveys to humans reading your code.

Answer (score 2):

Comments inline.

```
char*** get_chapter(FILE * infile) {
  int i=0;

  // This is a zero length array!
  // (The comma operator returns its right-hand value.)
  // Trying to modify any element here can cause havoc.
  char **chapter[10,000];

  while(chapter[i]=get_paragraph(infile)) { 
    // Do I read this right? I translate it as "if the first character of 
    // the first line of the first paragraph is not whitespace, we're done."
    // Not the paragraph just read in -- the first paragraph.  So this will exit
    // immediately or else loop forever and walk off the end of the array
    // of paragraphs.  I think you mean **chapter[i] here.
    if(!isspace(**chapter[0])){   
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }

  // Using pre-increment here means you leave one item in the array uninitialized
  // which can also cause a fault later on.  Use post-increment instead.
  // Also '\0' here is the wrong sort of zero; I think you need NULL instead.
  chapter[++i]='\0';

  char**(*chap) = malloc(i * sizeof(*chap));
  i=0;
  while(chapter[i]) {
    // This statement looks ambiguous to me.  Referencing a variable twice and
    // incrementing it in the same statement?  You may end up with an off-by-one error.
    chap[i] = chapter[i++];
  }

  // Wrong flavor of zero again.
  chap[i]='\0';
  return(chap);
}
```

Comment: " Do I read this right? I translate it as "if the first character of the first line of the first paragraph is not whitespace, we're done. Not the paragraph just read in -- the first chapter."  Your assuption is right.

Comment: Eep.  I meant "the first paragraph", not "the first chapter".  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if(!isspace(**chapter[i])){
```

Each `chapter[i]` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`, this `char` is the first character in each chapter. So `**chapter[i]` represents the first character in chapter `i`. Using `chapter[0]` will only look at the first chapter.

Comment: I don't know,  I only want to check the very first element in the line.  If [i] was there I would step through it, wouldn't I?

Comment: If you have a string `char* foo` and derefernce it using `*foo` you will get the first char in the string. `**chapter[i]` will give you the first `char` of each `chapter[i]`. Your current code only looks at the first chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried single stepping though it in gdb, and occasionally dumping the local variables to see the current state?  It's a good way to learn.  You may want to add a few extra intermediate variables that "info locals" will automatically dump as well (pointers to the current XXX, where XXX is various items in your hierarchy)

I assume a GNU environment:

```
% gcc -g homework.c -o hw
% gdb hw
(gdb) b 10
(gdb) r
(gdb) info locals
(gdb) n
(gdb) info locals
...
```

Replace "10" with a suitable line number near the beginning of the function.

Comment: I have stepped through with insight, that's why I think the problem is with checking the first element in the paragraph, but I am not 100% sure.